# How do I return text from the MediaWiki SearchAfterNoDirectMatch hook?

Tags: hook, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am trying to write a MediaWiki Search Hook that will list native files in the file system and then, eventually, allow a person to click on one of the files and view its content.

My extensions.json contains this:

```
        "Hooks": {
            "SearchAfterNoDirectMatch": "MediaWiki\\Extension\\NativeFileList\\Hooks::onSearchAfterNoDirectMatch"
        },
```

My Hooks::onSearchAfterNoDirectMatch file looks like this:

```
namespace MediaWiki\Extension\NativeFileList;

class Hooks {
        /**
         * @see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SearchAfterNoDirectMatch
         * @called from https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/g/mediawiki/core/+/master/includes/search/SearchNearMatcher.php
         * @param $searchterm
         * @param $title - array of titles
         * Returns true if it found something, false is otherwise
         */
        public static function onSearchAfterNoDirectMatch( $searchterm, &$title ) {
           $title=Title::newFromText( "test", "bar");
           return false;
    }

}
```

My problem is that no text is returned. Well, it's worse than that. With the above code, I get an exception (but I don't know how to debug it, because I can't see the exception). If I take the line setting `$title` out, it returns. If i change the line to `$title=undefined();` I get another error. If I set `$title="foo";` I get no error, but no foo.

So how do I return a search hit or, even better, a set of search hits?

None of the existing search plug-ins use the modern search Hook api, which is documented in these locations:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SearchAfterNoDirectMatch
- https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/g/mediawiki/core/+/master/includes/search/SearchNearMatcher.php
- https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classSearchNearMatcher.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SearchAfterNoDirectMatch` is used to return the title of a near-match, rather than to supplement the search results. For supplementing search results, use the `onSpecialSearchResultsAppend`. Here is code adds three lines to the search results:

```
class Hooks {
    /**
     * @see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SearchAfterNoDirectMatch
     * @called from https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/g/mediawiki/core/+/master/includes/search/SearchNearMatcher.php
     * @param $searchterm
     * @param $title - array of titles
     */
    public static function onSpecialSearchResultsAppend( $that, $out, $term ) {
        $out->addHTML("<h3>Extra Search Results:</h3>");
            $out->addHTML("<ul>");
            $out->addHTML("<li>Extra Result #1</li>");
            $out->addHTML("<li>Extra Result #2</li>");
            $out->addHTML("<li>Extra Result #3</li>");
            $out->addHTML("</ul>");
        }
    }
}
```

That should be enough to get most people going.

Answer (score 0):

That hook can't return text, you just can change the title in order to generate a match from the hook. $title has to be a Title object, if the code you posted above is the exact code you are using your exception is due to the second parameter not being one of the namespace constants like `NS_MAIN`